# How does a uniform magnetic field change when you put the magnets further apart?

Tags: electromagnetism

How does a uniform magnetic field change when you put the magnets further apart? I know it changes with non-uniform ones due to the density of the fieldlines, but if the fieldlines are uniform, they don't become denser right?
And if the magnetic field does not change, neither does the flux right.

But then why would that magnetic field decrease?

Comment: You are assuming that "the magnetic field does not change" because the field is uniform and then you are asking why "would that magnetic field decrease".  Not sure how it could decrease, if it is uniform and does not change. Could you possibly restate the question so it is not   self-contradicting?